# How to gracefully handle calling a method that may never return

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, clr, c#-5.0

In my C# MVC4 ASP.NET code (in a method on a controller) I call a function that I know has the possibility that it may never return.  It is a call to a Microsoft object that does not raise and error, does not time out, just hangs (and hangs and hangs).

I think I have found the cause of the specific incidents of why this has happened, but the general problem worries me and I want to guard against it (as it causes general problems on the server, rather than just isolated problems to the individual user).  I want to know the most graceful way of handling this sort of problem.

The method I am calling is [LocalReport.Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms252207%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=LocalReport.Render%20hangs&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-gbGG485GG485&oq=LocalReport.Render%20hangs&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62.7196j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows a number of people with a number of problems where this method never seems to return.

Comment: Normally in this instance you would get a time-out on the client-side? There isn't much else you can do if your server is effectively not responding?

Comment: First of all I would seriously consider not to call such a function that may hang or is not stable. Each request consumes a thread from the thread pool and too many of such calls can create problems.

Comment: Stongly agree that we should not be using this, if you want to check out some of the nastiness around SSRS check out this daily wtf link - http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Were-Going-to-Need-Another-Guru!.aspx .  However, there are some things I can change and some things I am stuck with and have to deal with the best I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at this answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/630920) I think the least worse solution is to wrap the offending call (to LocalReport.Render) into a separate Process and app domain. I will then kill the process if it starts behaving erratically.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try calling the method on a different Thread ? and abort the thread after a timeout ?

Although not a neat solution at all, but not a lot of options available in case there is no misconception about why the method hangs.

Comment: That is a "good" solution. Create a task and wait for it with a given time limit.

Comment: Aborting a thread is a very dangerous operation that is very hard to execute safely. Nobody should do it without understanding the severe ramifications.

Comment: I totally recognize that and that is why i mentioned that its not a neat solution.